# My Facebook App's icon isn't appearing when sharing

Tags: facebook, canvas, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook App (Page Tab, Website and Canvas) and since it's gone live I've updated the App Icon (1024x1024) but whenever someone shares the Canvas URL you still this:

[image]

How can I update this icon from Facebook's default image?

As I say, I've already updated the App Icon on the App Details page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXX/app-details/). Is there somewhere else that I need to update the Canvas icon?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple, and had nothing to do with the App Icon. Even though the user is sharing the Canvas URL, Facebook constructs the share data like it does for any website.

The issue was merely caching. I ran the Canvas URL through the Object Debugger (previous known as Linter) and it worked fine.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Simple!